# fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, filesystems

I keep getting this error message even If i just follow the sample example from [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

```
import fs from 'file-system';
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', (err) => {
          if (err) {console.log(err);}
          console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });
```

In the document, it has clearly mentioned that existsSync() is not depreciated. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can some one please help me with.

I have just updated my node version to 8.2.1, webpack 2.4.1.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you should do `import fs from 'fs'` or is there anything new in node.js that I missed?

Comment: fs is not available any more in npm.

Comment: Can you show me where you found that?
I am just using node 8.2.1 and used it without problems

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs

Comment: I replaced file-system with fs. And got another error.  
_fs2.default.writeFile is not a function

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't say that fs is not available.
I think you are using 'fs' from front end, because in node it works as before :)

Comment: Between fs is built-in node.js package and in most cases (99%) it is not supposed to be downloaded from npm

Comment: yes.. you're right. I'm working on react not on node js itself. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151553/discussion-between-mesmerize86-and-aren-hovsepyan).